# why can't recordAudioURL be assigned to the segue.destination object?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am following an online course and the instructor code has the following code, but I get an error. It might be an issue with updates on Swift or Xcode. How would you approach to fix this error?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "stopRecording" {
      let playsoundsVC = segue.destination as! PlaySoundsViewController
      let recordedAudioURL = sender as! URL
      playsoundsVC.recordedAudioURL = recordedAudioURL
   }
}
```

the last line of the code gives the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'URL' to type 'URL?.Type'

edit1: start of the `PlaySoundsViewController` file

```
class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {
  var recordedAudioURL = URL?.self
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure var inside `PlaySoundsViewController` is declared like this

```
class PlaySoundsViewController:UIViewController {
   var recordedAudioURL:URL?
}
```

or `var recordedAudioURL:URL!` if it's 100% it will be assigned

Comment: :-) I put = instead of : into my own code. The instructor code uses :URL!
so I fixed it. Still the error continues.

Comment: ok it seems to work correctly now. A lot was depending on this variable declaration and to get it wrong with = instead of : made the entire program work incorrectly. Now things are fine. Thank you